# program that gives both the hcf and gcd of two numbers

Tags: java

I'm a beginner, and this is for school. Please help me with this, it's got to be a very simple program that the user enters two numbers and the result is two numbers, one hcf and one gcd. 
I wrote the codes separately but I don't know how to combine them.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I will upvote if you can describe to me the algorithm you want to use.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide your codes here.

Comment: Based on observations: homework + Stackoverflow + no visible code + minimal understanding of the problem = bad idea.

Comment: @JoshM no matter if it homework but if OP shows what he tried for then its ok

Comment: @javaBeginner Very true. But quite evidently, the OP hasn't even made an attempt.

Comment: I swear to god, I've been working on this for the past two weeks and I don't have any older siblings, my parents don't know anything about this and my teacher won't help, he just said "this is too easy, you should be able to do it" well I can't!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your GCD program and take the code where you're calculating the GCD and move it into a function:

```
public int GCD(int a, int b) {
    //find GCD
    //return GCD
}
```

And do the same for HCF:

```
public int HCF(int a, int b) {
    //find HCF
    //return HCF
}
```

Then in the main method:

```
//all the code for prompting the user for input
//and all the code for asking the user for input
//code which you've already written if you wrote these two programs independently already
System.out.println("GCD of " + input1 + " and " + input2 + " is " + gcd(input1, input2));
System.out.println("HCF of " + input1 + " and " + input2 + " is " + hcf(input1, input2));
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `printf`, not `println`.

Comment: @JoshM Or what I just fixed it to